# Validate XML against XSD with JavaScript on client side

Tags: javascript, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am required to show a user an XMLfile in a friendly way as a result I am creating a tree like structure such as: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree instead of showing the user the raw XML.

Right now when creating a new node I am validating that on the server side. If the server validates the new proposed XML(tree) then I go ahead and create a new node for example.

Anyways now I will like to allow the user to drag these nodes. When dragging the nodes if I validate the proposed on the server side it will be to slow. **So my question is how can I validate an XML file against a schema on the client side** so that when dragging a node I can allow dragging the node or not depending whether or not the validation succeeds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the [xml.js](https://github.com/kripken/xml.js/) package, which exports an [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) object ported via [Emscripten](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/) from [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/).

Comment: Unfortunately that library seems to be US-centric and doesn't support UTF-8 characters. Seems to only work with basic ANSI characters.

Comment: @Nux: I see you've [filed an issue](https://github.com/kripken/xml.js/issues/26#issuecomment-634146238) to that effect.  Let us know if you're able to get resolution, find a work-around, or identify another library that works better for you.